# Spring Security: set session max inactive interval declaratively?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, session

How can I do it with java-config in Spring Boot application with (embedded Tomcat)?
I expected these settings to be declarative and configurable in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, like this:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login*","/signin/**","/signup/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/USER/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
            .formLogin()
            // setSessionMaxInactiveInterval(60*60);
    }
```

But there is no such settings?

The only way I am able do it is to extend the default [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) (which behavior is pretty suitable for my app) and add the needed logic there programmatically:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SessionSettingsHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private static final int MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL = 60; // sec

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL);
        log.debug("Session inactive interval: {}", MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL);
    }
}


  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login*","/signin/**","/signup/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/USER/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(sessionSettingsHandler);
    }
```

This works but I feel like these settings should exist in Spring Boot?

I also tried to set application.properties:
 *spring.session.timeout = 3600*

But these settings seem to be simply ignored by Spring Security.

Comment: How long a session lasts has nothing to do with Spring Boot or Spring Security. That is a setting of your Servlet container. Hence, assuming Spring Boot 2.x here, you should be using the `server.servlet.session.timeout` property.

Comment: So, I've set in application.properties the value of server.servlet.session.timeout=12s , logged in with a reserved login and password, reached the protected resource and in 12 sec I expected it to redirect to log-in page after F5, but it's not, I am still logged it! The settings again are ignored. Do I do anything wrong?

Comment: The reaper thread runs every minute, so setting a timeout lower then 1 minutes generally doesn’t have an effect.

Comment: I got it. It now works for 1 min timeout at least. Thank you for the deep insight!